# Capping progress of video as user scrolls

Tags: swift, scrollview

I'm working on a feature where we display a video on a view and we adjust the progress of the video according to the user scroll. So when the user scrolls down, we feed the y offset into a method, which maps to a progress level of no greater than 1.0, and we move the video to that progress position. When the user scroll back up, the progress reduces due to the y offset reducing, and so the video reverses. Here is the method in question:

```
   private var initialVisibleOffset: CGFloat?

   func mapScrollOffsetToProgression(_ offset: CGFloat) -> Double {
        guard let initialOffset = initialVisibleOffset else {
            initialVisibleOffset = offset
            return 0.0
        }

        let maxOffset: CGFloat = 500
        let filteredOffset = lowPassFilter(newValue: offset - initialOffset, oldValue: previousScrollOffset, alpha: 0.1)
        var progress = -Double(filteredOffset / maxOffset)

        previousScrollOffset = filteredOffset

        return min(max(progress, 0.0), 1.0)
    }
```

The `initialVisible` offset is set when the video first becomes visible in the scroll view to the user as we don't want to play the video when it is not in view.

Overall, this is working pretty well, except that as the user continues to scroll down and so the yOffset increases, whilst we are capping the progress at 1.0 it means that when the user starts to scroll back up, if the offset is greater than `maxOffset`, the progress remains at 1.0 until such a point that `-Double(filteredOffset / maxOffset)` yields a value which is less than 1.0. The result of this is that if the user has scrolled beyond the 500 max offset, it takes quite a lot of scrolling back up before the progress begins to move back down below 1.0 and so the video stays still.

The effect I need is that as soon as the user begins to scroll back up (and so long as the video is visible) then the progress begins to reduce, regardless of how high the offset is.